# Create a table like datatables.net example with parent/child and +/- responsive buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying build the same table as the example on https://datatables.net/

Below is the code I have already can someone help me figure out what I'm missing?

This is built on a wordpress site so wordpress is already calling the jquery. Here is a link to the site: http://dev.americasfinestlighting.com/products/annandale-column-mount-2/

http://pastebin.com/D0w89Grx

I would like have the parent child relationship for mobile. If you resize the example link above you will see the green and red expand/contract buttons.

Thanks, 
William

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to call the `DataTable()` function within a stylesheet.  Change `<style>` tag to `<script>`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myTable').DataTable();
});
</script>
```

DataTable requires jQuery, but you only included DataTable.  You also need to include the Responsive extension to DataTable (see here: https://datatables.net/download/release).  Copied to Codepen with jQuery included and all dependencies satisfied: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PNJqqz

Comment: I'm not sure how I missed that one... I updated the code and its still not working properly. http://pastebin.com/Xq7XWLAX

Comment: See my edit and my Codepen - you forgot to call jQuery.  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PNJqqz

Comment: I am getting the error: TypeError: $ is not a function when I try to load the page... Here is a link to the site: http://dev.americasfinestlighting.com/products/annandale-column-mount-2/

Comment: You need to upgrade to at least jQuery 1.7 or newer.  DataTables requires a newer version.

Comment: What version is my site running? I am running the most current version of WordPress. Also in your codepen the +/- responsive is not working with the parent child data.

Comment: The example you gave doesn't have this either.  Can you tell me what you mean?  You have jQuery 1.11.3 (looked like 1.1.3 at first).  But you also have jquery-migrate, which might conflict.

Comment: On the example if you grab the corner of your screen and resize you will see it.

Comment: omnichad any thoughts on this? I'm still trying to get this working... Thanks!

Comment: I don't know - my codepen copy works.  You might have to save a local copy of your HTML and try removing jquery-migrate or looking to see if something else in your code but not on this question is causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

you need to change the `<style>` tag for `<script>`, the difference is that  tag is to change base styles code for example:

```
<style type="text/css"> //this change the H1 elements properties
   H1 {border-width: 1; 
   border: solid; 
   text-align: center}
 </style>
```

and the `<script>` tag contains the script code like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   document.write("Hello Javascript!")
</script>
```

Comment: Please see comments below. I have already updated the <style> to <script>. Its still not working however... Any other thoughts?